# Javascript scopes and using of this keyword

Tags: javascript, scope

let's say that I have following code:

```
var obj = {
    element: null,
    init: function(){
        this.element = document.getElementById('element');
        var localElement = document.getElementById('element');

        // Option A...
        $(this.element).click(function(){
            $(this).hide();           // Option A1
            $(this.element).hide();   // Option A2
            $(element).hide();        // Option A3
        });

        // Option B...
        $(element).click(function(){
            $(this).hide();           // Option B1
            $(this.element).hide();   // Option B2
            $(element).hide();        // Option B3
        });
    }
}
```

I know that choosing one of them is just a question of taste. (EDIT: It's not, as alerted to me)

But what I would like to know is
There is any difference on evaluating by JS or... they are evaluated by the same algorithm?

**In case of difference**:
Which one is faster?
Which one is more "correct" or most close to good practice? (**if applicable**)
Can I assume the different times of evaluating of the element as irrelevant? (in a large loop)

And if I use local variable `localElement`?

**UPDATE:**

I've created a fiddle (slightly diff): http://jsfiddle.net/uD9eB/

In my tests A1, A3, B1, B3 worked. Obviously, the '2s (A2/B2) haven't.

Comment: For option "B" you meant `$(localElement)` right? Options "A1" and "B1" will work, and options "A3" and "B3" will too if you fix the references to `$(element)` to be `$(localElement)`.  Options "A2" and "B2" will not work.

Comment: No, i meant referencing directly without `this`, `localElement` would be a "C"

Comment: Well that won't work. There is no variable "element" in scope.  You cannot refer to `this.element` without including `this` in the expression. JavaScript is not like Java - there is never any implicit reference to object properties (well there's the `with` statement, but that's explicit in its own way).

Comment: So, "A3" is incorrect.. and is "B3" or entire "B" incorrect?

Comment: References to the identifier "element" without `this.` do not refer to `obj.element` so "B" won't work (the "click" assignment) and similarly inside the "click" handler only "B1" would work.

Comment: Why 2 votes down when the question is straightforward, I provided code and it's not trivial?

Comment: For who voted to close as opinion based: READ CAREFULLY WHAT I HAVE ASK!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take them one at a time.

`element` in option B doesn't exist, the code will throw an exception. If it doesn't throw an exception it is because you have a (probably global) variable element someplace else and it uses that instead of what you expect. Still, it is wrong.

Let's assume for the rest of the answer that option B uses `localElement` instead of the non-existing `element`.

**The difference between A and B:**

When you call `obj.init()`, `this` inside the `init` function is `obj`. So the first line `this.element = 'a';` sets the property `element` of `obj` to `'a'`;.

Inside the hadler jQuery sets `this` as the element that the event is associated on (or something like that, i'm not worried about details here). So inside both versions of the handlers, `this` will point to the same HTML Element.

So the only difference between A and B is the lookup speed of this.element vs localElement. I strongly advise you not to try to optimize that because the difference is imperceptible in any reasonable scenario.

**The difference between 1 2 and 3:**

1. Seeing how `this` will be an HTML Element:
   `$(this).hide()` will do what you expect: get a jQuery wrapper over the element, call hide() on it.
2. `this.element` is probably undefined, so `$(this.element).hide()` will probably do nothing.
3. `$(element).hide()` element doesn't exist, as explained above, so this will throw an error
4. Bonus: `$(localElement).hide()`, this will work, but will create a needless closure (because jQuery already provides the localElement as `this`, you don't need another reference to it), so it will be imperceptibly slower and less efficient.

The best way to do it would be **Option A1**.

Comment: The answer that I was looking for.. See my fiddle: Why B3 works?

Comment: Exactly why i said, because there is a global variable named element that you are using instead. Change the id of the input to `element1` (and the call of the function) and you will unmask the problem. This link shows you where the global element comes from: https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-14/document-elements-as-window

Comment: thansk! one more: i've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uD9eB/1/. I can use `obj.element` and `this`. Option A1 is still better?

Comment: It is similar to my bonus idea (4), in that it creates a closure where none is needed. I would still go with A1.

Answer (score 1):

From this code alone it's impossible to tell what `this` is bound to. But knowing jQuery, it's bound to `this.element` (A*) and `element` (B*) respectively.

It is not bound to `obj`.

In general, `this` is bound to whatever the caller wants to because you are freely allowed to change it with `Function.bind`, `Function.apply` and `Function.call`.

---

As for performance: Any call to `$` is (relatively) slow, so cache your references.

Comment: If I use A*, only A1 is correct... right?

Comment: Yes, A2 and A3 are undefined.